# Calendar Event Color

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I want to arrange different calendar events with different colors. I work on several projects, and use different colors to identify with calendar event corresponds to which project. My company uses Google calendar, but I use the Mac Calendar. I can not find a method to change specific events to the color I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are set in your Google calender (the Google web site).

There you can set the individual colors for the events.

[image: calender color]

The Mac Calender is using the Google calender settings, but you can not change the colors in your Mac Calender.

**UPDATE**

If you really want to use the Apple Calender there is a somewhat initially complicated process to set it up, but easy to use afterward.

You would in Google Calender make new Calenders (name them to your liking) like Events A ect.. then assign a color to it.

Now they will show in your Apple calender with the assigned color.

[image: calendar]

and you will see them in your calendar list

[image: list]

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks, I suppose, for confirming my fear.

Comment: Nice one - thanks for this clever solution !

Answer (score 0):

On OSX the Calendar app uses different colors to distinguish between different calendars being displayed in the app. Eg. any events added to my personal Calendar are green, but events added to my work calendar are blue.